# how to hide a div(shows range of slider) when slider handle's tooltip overlaps

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery UI slider. I added div1 & div2 to show the range of slider at both ends and slider handle has tool tip div3 to show the current value of slider. This div3 overlaps both div1 & div2 when slider handle comes close. So I wish to hide both div1 & div 2 when div3 comes close to each other...   Thanks...

Comment: Can you provide any code and/or [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t2hkD/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div1').hide();
```

This is equivalent to display:none. It hides an element, and it will not take up any space.

```
$('#div1').css("visibility", "hidden")
```

visibility:hidden hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before.

> [...] when div3 comes close to each other

This part I don't understand.

**/Edit:**

I updated your Fiddle, see the Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t2hkD/3/).

Comment: I wish to hide div1 when div3(div attached with slider handle) comes close and also for div2.. Both div1 & div2 must visible when div3 is not near to them.. Thanks...